# Troubleshooting Subversion connection failure

Tags: svn

I'm having some troubles connecting to our subversion box.  We connect to the subversion server over Hamachi VPN and this has been working for over a year.

Just recently, I am receiving a generic connection error:

> C:>svn info svn://subversion/repos/
>   svn: Can't connect to host
>   'subversion': A connection attempt
>   failed because the connected party did
>   not properly respond after a period of
>   time, or established connection failed
>   because connected host has failed to
>   respond.

I can resolve the subversion box through the Windows file manager.  I've disabled the firewall for testing.  I can connect to server from other clients on the VPN network, so that's pointing to an issue on my laptop.  Beyond that, I don't know how to troubleshoot this issue.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try:

```
ping subversion
```

if that succeeds, then:

```
telnet subversion 3690
```

If a basic connection is functional you will get a line like:

```
( success ( 2 2 ( ) ( edit-pipeline svndiff1 absent-entries
commit-revprops depth log-revprops partial-replay ) ) )
```

If that doesn't work then look to see if the subversion server was disabled or if the default port number was altered.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  I can ping subversion, but telnet on that port doesn't work.  However, it works from another remote machine on the VPN network.  It seems to be on the client side.

Comment: I've traced this back to an issue with the DNS.  OpenDNS is resolving the request to the subversion host incorrectly.  The file browse to host works OK.  But pinging the host actually resolves to the OpenDNS name server.  Your post helped me track that down.  thx

Comment: I'm glad it helped in some small way!